# Loading hammer using require js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, hammer.js, js-amd

My project currently has both jquery.hammer and hammer.js. How do I access only hammer.js for a particular scope using requirejs?

Hammer.js has the following define module:

```
if ( typeof define == TYPE_FUNCTION && define.amd ) {
    define( function () {
        return Hammer;
    } );
} else if ( typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports ) {
    module.exports = Hammer;
} else {
    window[exportName] = Hammer;
}
```

I am trying to load it using the following code -

```
    require( ['hammer'], function ( Hammer ) {
        mod = Hammer; // Do something later with mod
    } );
```

I am getting this error: "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
            return Hammer;
        }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch "

Answer (score 1):

You have to name your module:

```
if (typeof define == TYPE_FUNCTION && define.amd) {
    define('hammer',function() {
        return Hammer;
    });
} else if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = Hammer;
} else {
    window[exportName] = Hammer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this error may happen when you add hammer js in a script tag in your html, if this your case remove it and just depend on requirejs for loading it